# Trying to validate a name field to be sure it is all alpha characters or a hyphen or apostrophe

Tags: php, regex

```
if(!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z'-]/",$First)) { die ("invalid first name");}
```

the above only flags input as invalid when the field is all numeric. combinations of letters and numbers pass ok.  Some help here for a newby please.  thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$First)) { die ("invalid first name");}
```

The `^` matches the beginning of the string, the `$` matches the end of the string and `+` after a character group means "one or more" matching characters.

Comment: copying this still throws an error when O'Brien tries to enter his name.

Comment: @AuntJamaima: that's not really in the scope of the question, in which the OP was specific about the characters he wanted to allow.  If you're having difficulty with a regex that will allow characters **you** need, you'll need to ask a new question.

Comment: FWIW, I tested the `O'Brien` name and it works fine. I can only imagine that @AuntJemima had whitespace (perhaps from when the input was submitted) and this was not cleared. Performing something such as `$first = trim("O'Brien ")` will fix this problem.

Comment: I think that it's a bad answer since it will not allow specials chars like àéèëüïöôü ...

Answer (score 4):

You're only matching a single character. You need to add a wildcard like `+` (1 or more). Also you're matching anywhere in the string. You need to add anchors (`^` for start of string, `$` for end of string) to make sure there are no invalid characters.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/", $First)) { die ("invalid first name");}
```

Alternatively you can look for a non-matching character:

```
if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z'-]/", $First)) { die ("invalid first name");}
```

The `^` inside the square brackets here means "any character that is NOT one of these".

Comment: This would still flag OK for `123abc456`. *EDIT* now it's right :-)

Answer (score 3):

In this case better to look for invalid characters than to try and match all of the characters, once a single invalid character appears, the search can quit and return failure. This is more efficient than always scanning the whole string.

```
if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z'-]/", $First)) { die ("invalid first name"); }
```

the ^ inside the set [] makes it match everything not in the set. and since the string is invalid if we have even one invalid character, there is no need for the set to have a repetition operator.

Even better would be a more helpful error message

```
if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z'-]/", $First, $Inv)) { die ("{$Inv[0]} not allowed in first name"); }
```

Comment: Not to be rude, but why are you even *mentioning* efficiency in this context?  You'd have to use the profiling equivalent of the Large Hadron Collider to measure the performance differential between these two approaches. :P

Comment: @Alan: it's never harmful to _know_ which of a set of choices is more efficient, although in this case, the overhead of choosing php probably does swamp out the differences.

Answer (score 2):

Adding accented characters is probably smart too, so that "Pierre Bézier" can fill out your form. Adding:

```
À-ÿ
```

.. to your regex will do that. Something like this, with everything included:

```
/^([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ-' ]+)$/
```

Comment: This give `Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 15`

Comment: interesting trick, it worked for me in JS and allows special chars, should be the selected answer : )

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, incase you want FULL NAME e.g. "JOHN RAMBO"

While the HTML FORM.PHP

```
<div class="error"><?php echo $error['name']; ?></div>
<input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $input['name']; ?>" class="inputf">
```

PHP CONTACT PAGE

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]/", $input['name']))
{
    // name is in-valid
    $error['name'] = 'Invalid Name';
    include('views/form.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an solution I was able to come up with. Should be able to handle your validation issues for names that have apostrophes, hypens and spaces.

```html
 if(!preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]+[\'-]?[a-zA-Z]+[ ]?)+$/', $string))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/", $firstName)) {` it will also match if an error occured, like a invalid regexp, because the `!` matches for both the return values `FALSE` and `0`.

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):
`preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.`

So the best way of making sure that the name is valid by your requirements is:

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/", $firstName) === 1) {
    die('Valid name');
} else {
    die('Invalid name or error');
}
```